# .NET Core 6 Web Api Authentication/ Authorization not working

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, swagger, authorization, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have written a small .NET 6 minimal web api, which is heavily based on / copied from a tutorial I did. The tutorial worked as expected, but I have two problems in my version.

The first problem is with swagger. When I uncomment the line `c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();` in AddSwaggerGen() I get a swagger error in the browser "Failed to load API definition. Fetch error. response status is 500 https://localhost:7123/swagger/v1/swagger.json"

The second problem is (when the swagger line is commented out to get it to run) nothing is secured. Either from swagger or from the browser I can access all endpoints.

Here is my `program.cs`. It certainly looks like I have everything in the right place. Even so, I would have expected that if it was misconfigured, it would prevent me from accessing the endpoints.

```
using DataAccess.DbAccess;
using MyAuthAPI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(
    c => {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyAPI", Version = "v1" });
        c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
            Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });
        // When this line is uncommented I get a swagger error- Failed to load api
        //    c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
    });
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISqlDataAccess, SqlDataAccess>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPersonAuthData, PersonAuthData>();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddJwtBearer(options => {
         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
             ValidateIssuer = false,
             ValidateAudience = false
         };
     });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

// app.UseStatusCodePages();       

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.ConfigureRoutes();

app.Run();
```

The routes and db access etc all works fine, but here is the routes.cs file just in case.

```
using DataAccess.DTOs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace MyAuthAPI;

[Authorize]
public static class Routes
{
    public static void ConfigureRoutes(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.MapGet("PersonAuths", GetPersonAuths);
        app.MapGet("PersonAuths/{id}", GetPersonAuth);
        app.MapPost("Login", Login);

    }

    private static async Task<IResult>GetPersonAuths(IPersonAuthData data)
    {
        try
        {
            return Results.Ok(await data.GetPersonAuths());
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Results.Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<IResult> GetPersonAuth(int id, IPersonAuthData data)
    {
        try
        {
            var results = await data.GetPersonAuth(id);
            if (results == null) return Results.NotFound();
            return Results.Ok(results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Results.Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }

 
    [AllowAnonymous]
    private static async Task<IResult> Login(LoginDTO loginDetails, IPersonAuthData data)
    {
        try
        {
            string jwt = await data.Login(loginDetails);
            if (jwt != "")
            {
                return Results.Ok(jwt);
            } else
            {
                return Results.Unauthorized();
            }
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Results.Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    
}
```

Thanks

**Edit**
The swagger issue looks like it may be due to Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters not supporting minimal apis.
[Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters)

Comment: mostly error is coming from swagger setup, Can you do a postman call, even if swagger has thrown this error?

Comment: Yes I can make a postman call to one of the endpoints, but I am not authenticated, so it should return a 401 or some sort of error. None of the end points are secured

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't see the `[Authorize]` attribute applied to your `Routes` class. Apply `[Authorize]` to the `GetPersonAuths` and `GetPersonAuth` methods instead and it should fix that problem.

Comment: @KirkLarkin - Perfect. Thanks very much. I have to say though, it does seem like a recipe for accidentally letting an unprotected endpoint slip through. I would have thought the approach would be if Authorization is turned on in program.cs then if nothing else is specified on the end point then it would be inaccessible. Thank you.

Comment: You can set a fallback policy that requires authorization by default.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks. I'll check it out. Obviously I have some way to go still :)